# Add permission for android instrumentation test only

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-instrumentation

I'd like to add `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` to let the test app know when the target app **com.example.dummy** is running or not. I added a separate AndroidManifest.xml file to androidTest folder with the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.dummy.test">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
</manifest>
```

and in gradle file:

```
    sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

and now I try to use "pm grant" just to see whether or not I can grant `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` to test app:

```
adb shell pm grant com.example.dummy.test android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
```

The problem - I get the following error:

```
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.example.dummy.test has not requested permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
```

The question is how can I add this permission only to androidTest correctly, i.e. so this permission will be available for **com.example.dummy.test** package?